# SecTransformExecute() crashes the app with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, macos, security-framework

I have a private/public key pair and I'm trying to encrypt a String with either of them. The code is running on OSX 10.11 and Xcode 7.2

```
func encryptMessageWithKey(message: String, keyType: KeyType,
    withCompletionBlock: (success: Bool, data: NSData?, error: AsymCryptoExceptions.Exceptions?)
    -> Void) {

        let uintData = [UInt8](message.utf8)
        let sourceData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, uintData, uintData.count)
        let privKey = self.getPrivateKeyReference()!
        var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        let encoder = SecEncryptTransformCreate(privKey, &errorRef)

        SecTransformSetAttribute(encoder,
            kSecPaddingKey,
            kSecPaddingPKCS1Key,
            &errorRef)

        SecTransformSetAttribute(encoder,
            kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
            sourceData,
            &errorRef)

        var encryptedData = SecTransformExecute(encoder, &errorRef)

        if (errorRef != nil) {
            let error = errorRef!.takeRetainedValue()
            print(error)
        }
}
```

The above is failing miserably, causing the app to crash at runtime with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`. No errors, nothing.

My research has shown that there might be a bug related to explicitly specifying `kSecPaddingPKCS1Key` as opposed to NULL which will set the padding to PKCS1 by default. However, I wasn't able to set this value to NULL since Swift has replaced that with nil and that can't be used in this spot.

Comment: Check out this post which steps through this: http://netsplit.com/swift-generating-keys-and-encrypting-and-decrypting-text

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @RobKeniger No, I stopped working on the project ...

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a pretty old question, I will answer it to maybe save someone else some time :)

I had the same problem where `SecTransformExecute` gave an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I noticed that the error would only occur when I changed or cleaned the project and rebuilt the app, but not when I would run the same debug build.

In the end, signing the application with a development certificate is what solved it for me, since before the app could not use the key due to the different automatic signing identities provided by Xcode.